# Resource Management when rendering into a device context (CDC/HDC)

Tags: winapi, mfc, gdi

I have a few questions about the drawing of a stroke in MFC. Suppose class CStroke has been declared beforehand. The sample code is shown below.

```
BOOL CStroke::DrawStroke(CDC* pDC)
{
    CPen penStroke;
    if ( !penStroke.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, m_nPenWidth, m_color) )
        return FALSE;
    CPen *pOldPen = pDC->SelectObject(&penStroke);
    pDC->MoveTo(m_pointArray[0]);

    for( int i = 0; i < m_pointArray.GetSize(); i++ )
    {
        pDC->LineTo(m_pointArray[i]);
    }

    pDC->SelectObject(pOldPen);
    return TRUE;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why do I need the pOldPen?
2. Why need I use `pDC->SelectObject(pOldPen)` to select pOldPen in the end?

Comment: quite simple: to change the pen back to what it was before.

Comment: Has the pen changed during the drawing?

Comment: Yes: --> penStroke.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, m_nPenWidth, m_color)

Comment: So,pOldPen records the pen being replaced by penStroke?

Comment: Selecting the previously selected resource back into a device context when you're finished is required to allow proper resource management. Consider a scenario, where `CStroke::DrawStroke` is part of more complex rendering and the code calling into `DrawStroke` has itself created and selected a pen into the device context. When `DrawStroke` returns, the calling code needs to be able to manage its resources, so it needs to have the same pen selected into the device context.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: actually `pDC->SelectObject(&penStroke)` and not `penStroke.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, m_nPenWidth, m_color) ` does the change.

Comment: @Michael Walz : yes I know that! I was refering to it as creating a new pen (obviously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

1. Why do I need the `pOldPen`?

   Because you owe it to your caller. It wasn't meant as a gift.
2. Why need I use `pDC->SelectObject(pOldPen)` to select `pOldPen` in the end?

   Because selecting another resource into a DC is the only way to select the current resource back out of the DC.

---

A device context uses GDI resources on your behalf when selecting them into a DC by calling [`SelectObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162957.aspx). At any one time a DC has exactly one [graphics object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144962.aspx) of each type (Pen, Brush, Bitmap, ...) selected into it. However, it does not manage the resources for you. Resource management is left to the application.

Unfortunately, the MFC implementation above hides one important detail with respect to resource management. Translating the code into a plain WinAPI implementation will make it more apparent what [`CPen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czhcb94f.aspx) is hiding:

```
BOOL CStroke::DrawStroke(HDC hDC)
{
    // Create a new pen resource
    HPEN penStroke = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, m_nPenWidth, m_color);
    if ( penStroke == NULL )
        return FALSE;

    // Select it into the device context
    HPEN oldPen = static_cast<HPEN>( SelectObject(hDC, &penStroke) );

    // Render strokes
    if ( m_pointArray.GetSize() > 0 )  // bugfix *
    {
        pDC->MoveTo(m_pointArray[0]);

        for( int i = 1; i < m_pointArray.GetSize(); i++ )  // bugfix **
        {
            pDC->LineTo(m_pointArray[i]);
        }
    }

    // Select pen out of DC
    HPEN penCreatedAbove = static_cast<HPEN>( SelectObject(hDC, oldPen) );

    // Clean up our resource (this is what CPen::~CPen() hides)
    DeleteObject(penCreatedAbove)

    return TRUE;
}
```

Since the code above creates a graphics object (see [`CreatePen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183509.aspx)) it is responsible for releasing the resources associated with it as well. To release a resource an application calls [`DeleteObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183539.aspx). This API call has the following requirement:

> Do not delete a drawing object (pen or brush) while it is still
>   selected into a DC.

In order to meet that precondition the pen created in the code above needs to be selected out of the DC. This is what the call to `SelectObject(hDC, oldPen)` does. (I made this more obvious by introducing a variable to store the return value.)

Since you have to select *something* into a DC to pull your resource back out, there are very few options really: The only graphics object that you neither own nor have to destroy at this point is `oldPen`. This also ensures that you can nest rendering code as illustrated in the following pseudo code:

```
HPEN bestPenEver = CreatePen();
HPEN oldPen = SelectObject(bestPenEver);

// Do some painting with bestPenEver

    call DrawStroke()

// Do some more painting with bestPenEver
SelectObject(oldPen);
DeleteObject(bestPenEver);
```

For completeness and to line up this implementation with the MFC code here are the relevant MFC-implementations:

```
CPen::CreatePen(int nPenStyle, int nWidth, COLORREF crColor)
{ return Attach(::CreatePen(nPenStyle, nWidth, crColor)); }
```

`CPen penStroke` is an automatic variable so it's destructor runs when control leaves the enclosing block (i.e. when `DrawStroke` returns). The destructor calls it's base class implementation `CGdiObject::DeleteObject` as follows:

```
BOOL CGdiObject::DeleteObject()
{
    if (m_hObject == NULL)
        return FALSE;
    return ::DeleteObject(Detach());
}
```

---

bugfix * No longer accesses first element of an empty sequence.

bugfix ** First element was already used for `MoveTo`.